# How to properly url encode accents?

Tags: python, escaping, urllib2, urlencode

I need to url encode foreign names, like "Misère".

When I do:

```
urllib2.quote(name)
```

I get a the error:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib.py", line 1205, in quote
    res = map(safe_map.__getitem__, s)
KeyError: u'\xe8'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
urllib2.quote(s.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement to @苏妍倩's answer would be to include safe characters in the method call. By default, urllib2.quote() only includes `/` `_` `-` `.` as a safe character which means characters like `:` will be converted, rendering the url useless.

For example:

```
url = https://www.zomato.com/pittsburgh/caffè-damore-catering-pittsburgh
print urllib2.quote(url.encode('utf-8'))
>>> https%3A//www.zomato.com/pittsburgh/caff%C3%A8-damore-catering-pittsburgh

print urllib2.quote(url.encode('utf-8'),':/')
>>> https:////www.zomato.com/pittsburgh/caff%C3%A8-damore-catering-pittsburgh
```

Notice the slight difference in outputs in the https portion of the url.

Hopefully this saves someone else the time it took me to figure this out!